# Where can I get decibel level data for NBA games?

Tags: data-request, sports

I am trying to find data that reports the decibel level at NBA games. I prefer as granular as possible - minute-by-minute would be fantastic.

Comment: It would be really cool if this data set existed.

Comment: What do you plan to do with this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an incredibly specific data request -- I don't think there's any chance of just finding this in the wild. Your best bet is probably to obtain TV recordings of NBA (either record them yourself or hunt around online) and analyze the decibel levels in audio track yourself. Of course, this has a few issues: you'll have to cut out commercial breaks/instant replays/etc, you'll have to somehow filter out the commentators or something (the commentators' volume should be consistent on average over the course of the game, so this should be feasible, if not ideal), etc.

That's a lot of work and it won't produce the most accurate results, but I think that's the best you're going to get in the realm of *open* data.

Comment: is this entirely speculative? studies have been done on noise levels at sports events before, albeit not nba (to my knowledge)...moreover, the method you describe (is actually wicked clever! nicely done!) i think (here i am speculating) would wield very shaky data. sorry if this sounds critical, not my point, and i think your idea is quite novel. but i still wonder if this is simply speculation?

Comment: Yes this is mostly speculative. I imagine there are studies that exist but I think the likelihood of finding the raw decibel level data is pretty low. But I'd love to be proven wrong!